# User Location is automatically called

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, userlocation

In my code, I need to initialize my user Location: it works fine.

But whenever I want to change my location (by selecting an adress or sweeping on the screen) my app brings me back to my user Location.

I found a bit of an answer on [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22594104/user-location-mapkit-viewdidload). 
But, I don't call `didUpdateUserLocation()` . So I don't know what to do.

Does my app call frequently `ViewDidLoad()` ?

Here is my code, where I initialize my locations.

```
var usrLocation: CLLocationManager!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()) {
        usrLocation = CLLocationManager()
        usrLocation.delegate = self
        usrLocation.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        usrLocation.requestLocation()
        usrLocation.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    mapView.delegate = self
}
```

Also, I can not just delete my `usrLocation.requestLocation()` function, I need to center on my user at the app launching. I thought of calling it elsewhere, but I have no idea of where ?

Comment: Don't call both `requestLocation()` and `startUpdatingLocation()`.  Call `requestLocation()` if you just want to get the user's current location once and `startUpdatingLocation()` if you want continuous location updates.

Comment: Oh, it was that. Thank's a lot. You should put it in a true answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as dan said, the problem was that I shouldn't call `requestLocation()` and `startUpdatingLocation().`

So right now my code is like that, and it works perfectly:

```
var usrLocation: CLLocationManager!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()) {
        usrLocation = CLLocationManager()
        usrLocation.delegate = self
        usrLocation.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        usrLocation.requestLocation()
    }
    mapView.delegate = self
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have implemented
usrLocation.startUpdatingLocation()

This is keep on updating location, so as soon you point to another location, it updates the user location.

Remove this line the code will work.

Comment: I know, I posted it 20 minutes ago :) Thanks

Comment: Sure, I didn't checked that, but great you find the solution :)